# Unity RegisterTypes not work properly

Tags: c#, unity-container

I use Unity as IoC. I like to register some classes in the container with RegisterTypes as follows:

```
container.RegisterTypes(
                                AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath(), 
                                WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
                                WithName.TypeName, 
                                WithLifetime.PerResolve
                                );
```

But the Types arn't  instanced.My Interface class is:

```
namespace Taschenrechner
{
public interface IBerechne
{
    int Berechnen(Formel formel);
}
}
```

And my Classes:

```
class Addition : IRechenoperation
{
    public char Operator
    {
        get
        {
            return '+';
        }
    }

    public int Berechnen(int operand1, int operand2)
    {
        return operand1 + operand2;
    }
}

class Subtraktion : IRechenoperation
{
    public char Operator
    {
        get
        {
            return '-';
        }
    }

    public int Berechnen(int operand1, int operand2)
    {
        return operand1 - operand2;
    }
}
```

And the construktor in wich i like to Injekt this Types is as follows:

```
    public Parser(Formel formel,IRechenoperation[] rechenoperationen)
    {
        this.ergebnisformel = formel;
        this.rechenoperationen = rechenoperationen;
    }
```

When i execute the Code rechenoperationen is always an empty array.

Comment: Unless there's something I'm missing, you are showing an interface (`IBerechne`) which your classes are not implementing (they are implementing `IRechenoperation`). Just to be sure, are your `Addition` and `Subtraktion` classes being found by `AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath()`?

Comment: I did a mistake in the example should be this Interface:
public interface IRechenoperation
    {
        int Berechnen(int operand1, int operand2);
        char Operator { get; }
    }

Comment: Again, have you checked `Addition` and `Subtraktion` are there in the returned enumerable from `AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath()`?

Comment: The classes arn't found by AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath() but i don't no why they arn't found

Comment: Have you tried marking the classes `public`?

Comment: Thanks yes that's the problem the classes must be public.

Comment: I'll add an answer with extended information

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath()` is not finding your `Addition` and `Subtraktion` types because they are `internal`.

The most obvious way to make it find them would be making them `public`.

You could actually make it work with `internal` but it's not recommended (resolution of internal or private dependencies is just a not recommended practice) and would be "hacky" to say the least (using `InternalsVisibleTo`, if you want to google it). If it's an absolute must I could expand on this, but you'd need to provide more details about how your projects are structured on the solution.